# How to use replace function to remove "Enter"?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file need to delete press enter (it means `\n`).

The following is the CSV file example:

```
Rorschach.,11/1/2020 02:40," 
 https://upload.cc/i1/2020/01/11/XcGyfD.png 

 "
Rorschach.,11/1/2020 02:42," 
答定manaman先 抗爭幣（壽終正寢）最有用 /faces/agree.gif #yup# 

 "
manaman,11/1/2020 04:28," 
教協竟然聽從國師講, 反黃色經濟圈 熱狗 /faces/dead.gif xx( 

 "
```

I tried to use `new_html_code = re.sub("\n", "", original_html_code)` to remove enter function(\n), but is is not work.

The following is my expect result:

```
Rorschach.,11/1/2020 02:40,"  https://upload.cc/i1/2020/01/11/XcGyfD.png  "
Rorschach.,11/1/2020 02:42," 答定manaman先 抗爭幣（壽終正寢）最有用 /faces/agree.gif #yup#  "
manaman,11/1/2020 04:28," 教協竟然聽從國師講, 反黃色經濟圈 熱狗 /faces/dead.gif xx(  "
```

How can I correct my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    new_lines = ""
    with open("./so.csv", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line.strip() == "":
                continue
            if "\n" in line and line.strip() != '"':
                new_lines += line.replace("\n", "")
                continue
            new_lines += line
    print(new_lines)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

With this little snippet I loaded your file into string variable in the shape you wanted to, but there are certainly better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `csv` module?  If using it as documented with `newline=''` your newlines are untranslated and the default `excel` dialect uses `'\r\n'`, but even so your *data content* new lines might be something else.

The `print` in the code below will make it clear:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv','r',encoding='utf8',newline='') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    with open('fixed.csv','w',encoding='utf8',newline='') as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        for row in reader:
            print(repr(row))
            row[2] = row[2].replace(reader.dialect.lineterminator,'')
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Console output (note the `\r\n` newlines):

```
['orschach.', '11/1/2020 02:40', ' \r\n https://upload.cc/i1/2020/01/11/XcGyfD.png \r\n\r\n ']
['Rorschach.', '11/1/2020 02:42', ' \r\n答定manaman先 抗爭幣（壽終正寢）最有用 /faces/agree.gif #yup# \r\n\r\n ']
['manaman', '11/1/2020 04:28', ' \r\n教協竟然聽從國師講, 反黃色經濟圈 熱狗 /faces/dead.gif xx( \r\n\r\n ']
```

File output:

```
orschach.,11/1/2020 02:40,  https://upload.cc/i1/2020/01/11/XcGyfD.png  
Rorschach.,11/1/2020 02:42, 答定manaman先 抗爭幣（壽終正寢）最有用 /faces/agree.gif #yup#  
manaman,11/1/2020 04:28," 教協竟然聽從國師講, 反黃色經濟圈 熱狗 /faces/dead.gif xx(  "
```